# ¿Como instalar la extension BLENC.dll PHP?

Tags: php, xampp

Descargué la extensión y la pegué en C:/xampp/php/ext
después reinicié el servidor, pero nada, sale Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt().

¿que debo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que modificar el php.ini para cargarla:

```
extension=blenc.dll
```

Puedes mirar más información en http://php.net/manual/es/install.pecl.windows.php

Aquí se explica con un caso realmente parecido al tuyo: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phpdesktop/YMJeQIqYNzo

Dicen:

- Extrae del zip original y copia php_blenc.dll en la carpeta "C:/xampp/php/ext"
- Edita el fichero php.ini y añade:

  extension=php_blenc.dll

  blenc.key_file="C:\xampp\php\ext.blenc_keys"

Supongo que te faltará la segunda línea.

Comment: Coloqué extension=php_blenc.dll en la carpeta 'C:/xampp/php/ext' y nada me sigue saliendo "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt()".

Comment: En la carpeta 'C:/xampp/php/ext' no tienes que poner eso, tienes que ponerlo en el php.ini, si miras el enlace que te paso lo explican muy bien.

Comment: Mi error @track3r no me expliqué, el archivo php_blenc.dll lo coloqué en C:/xampp/php/ext y el php.ini coloqué extension=php_blenc.dll con  extension_dir="C:\xampp2\php\ext"

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para añadir un enlace con tu mismo caso y una breve descripción.... te faltaría poner el key_file, supongo.

Comment: Voy a revisarlo y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme.